# Passing data to an endpoint using Axios in a react application

Tags: spring, reactjs, axios

I will like to pass a list to an endpoint using Axios within
a react application. At the moment I am not able to hit the endpoint.
All I get is this

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Required List parameter 'invoiceIds' is not present"
```

How can I pass this list with success?

Here is the list I intend to pass to the endpoint

```
    const mylist =["22277601","44123940"];
```

Here is the code for the endpoint

```
    @GetMapping({"customers/{customerId}/invoices/products"})
    public Page<starter> getProductsForInvoices(
            @PathVariable(required = false) Long customerId,
            @RequestParam List<Long> invoiceIds,
            Pageable pageInfo) {

        result = ...

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the Axios call

```
     AXIOS.get(`${API}/customers/123/invoices/products`, null, { params: {
        mylist

      }})
      .then(response => response.status)
      .catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

Comment: { params: { 'invoiceIds' : mylist }}

Comment: This did not work. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you share a sandbox with the code? It'll be easier for me to debug. I have a feeling the issue could be with you api too

Comment: You are actually correct. I had to add the required=false to my endpoint and I was able to hit the endpoint. I am not sure what this means.   @RequestParam(required = false) String invoiceIds,

Comment: It means the invoicesId is not a necessity for the api endpoint to query your db. But with that change now you can check what you get on your endpoint by printing it to a log file

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using get? Not entirely sure of your use case but would this be better suited using a post?

Second thing, pass in params as the second argument. You have null, where you should be passing in the object with the params object in side of it. In other words just flip those last to arguments your passing in.

Also name your key invoiceids then the value as your list.

Comment: can you please show a sample code from what I have ? Thanks

Comment: I am using get because I am retrieving a lot of data back to the client. I am not writing to the database so no need for post.

Comment: Cool makes sense.

 `AXIOS.get(`${API}/customers/123/invoices/products`, { 
       params: {
            invoiceIds: mylist,
      }})
      .then(response => response.status)
      .catch(err => console.warn(err));`

Comment: No luck. All am getting is this..  origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: This is a common problem and lots of articles online about fixing CORS errors. Essentially set yourresponse headers to allow all domains like this
`app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});`